# Disable wizard pane buttons in parent based on BooleanProperty in child

Tags: javafx

I've created a wizardpane in JavaFX, in which the user navigates through the wizard through the buttons in the bottom of the pane. The actual content of the pane (marked with a red square in the image below) is represented by a separate FXML file, which is imported as a child in the wizardpane on initialization.

[image: Wizard]

To the Child Controllers, I've added a BooleanProperty, which will be my check in the Parent Controller if all the fields in that step of the wizard have been filled in and are correct. This BooleanProperty is therefore changed within the Child Controller.
A ChangeListener in the Parent Controller checks the value of the BooleanProperty. However, I have to add and remove this ChangeListener each time the user moves to another step in the wizard. When I try to add the ChangeListener to the Child Controller of the first step, I get a NullPointerException, which makes no sense to me. The code for the ChangeListener is as follows:

```
ChangeListener<Boolean> booleanPropertyListener = new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
                        Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {

        nextButton.setDisable(!newValue.booleanValue());
    }};
```

And adding the ChangeListener to the first step:

```
stepOneController.isValidated.addListener(booleanPropertyListener);
```

Does someone have an idea what causes the NullPointerException? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: So [what's null](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~johns/npe.html)? Use a debugger or output statements to see.  Is it the `nextButton`, the `newValue`, `isValidated` or `stepOneController`?  If you can't work it out yourself and would like assistance from somebody else, you will probably need to provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that somebody could duplicate your error.

Comment: @jewelsea: Thanks, that was the right way to approach the problem. stepOneController was null, since I tried to set the controller (FXML loader.getController()) before I actually loaded the FXML file with loader.load(). Think I'm going to use the debugger more often... Anyways, thanks for your help!